# Sum two input values in realtime

Tags: php, jquery, html, sum, real-time

I want to sum two different inputs in a third realtime variable. I will explain better what I want:

1 variable : 100 (input)

2 variable : 150 (input)

sum : 250 (not input)

How can I do this?

Comment: Please post your try...what code have you tried by yourself so far?

Comment: You want it in the front end?

Comment: Basically you want data-binding similar to angular framework without any framework.

Comment: Show us what you have tried or researched. Stackoverflow is not a free code writing service. The objective here is to help you fix **your code** not do your work for you

Answer (score 0):

For realtime operations that is based on the client side events are managed by JavaScript and not PHP, which is server side. So to do something like what you wanted, we can use a `keyboard` event like `keyup` and make the third one `readonly`:

```js
$(function () {
  $("#id-1, #id-2").keyup(function () {
    $("#id-3").val(+$("#id-1").val() + +$("#id-2").val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="id-1" />
<input type="number" id="id-2" />
<input type="number" id="id-3" readonly />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is also a version in plain javascript:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<input type="text" id="val1">
<input type="text" id="val2">
<input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="calculate();">
<script>

function calculate(){

var val1 = document.getElementById('val1').value;
var val2 = document.getElementById('val2').value;
var res = (parseFloat(val1)+parseFloat(val2))

alert(res);

}


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would anyday recommend not using client side to handle such use cases but if you need to get it done using JS(`JQuery`), have a look below:

If HTML:

```
<input class="one" type="number" />
<input class="two" type="number" /> 

<p class="result"></p>
```

then JQuery should be:

```
$(".one, .two").keyup(function() {
  if($('.one').val() != "" && $('.two').val() != "") {
    var result = parseInt($('.one').val()) + parseInt($('.two').val());
    $('.result').text(result);
  }
});
```

```js
$(".one, .two").keyup(function() {
  if($('.one').val() != "" && $('.two').val() != "") {
    var result = parseInt($('.one').val()) + parseInt($('.two').val());
    $('.result').text(result);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="one" type="number" />
<input class="two" type="number" /> 

<p class="result"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".one, .two").keyup(function() {
  if($('.one').val() != "" && $('.two').val() != "") {
    var result = parseInt($('.one').val()) + parseInt($('.two').val());
    $('.result').text(result);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="one" type="number" value="2" />
<input class="two" type="number" value="5"/> 

<p class="result"></p>
```